# Fourier transforming the wave equation twice

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, fourier-transform, differential-equations, dirac-delta-distributions

The *wave equation*
$$\nabla^2 u(r,t)-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}(r,t)=0$$
can be Fourier transformed **with respect to time**, using $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=i\omega$, to obtain the *Helmholtz equation*:
$$\nabla^2 u(r,\omega)+\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}u(r,\omega)=0\,.$$
What I don't understand is what happens if we Fourier transform is subsequently **with respect to space**:
$$-k^2 u(k,\omega)+\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}u(k,\omega)=0\,,$$
since we now get
$$\left(-k^2+\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\right)u(k,\omega)=0\,.$$
If this should hold for all $k$ and all $\omega$, the solution is the zero function, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When solving PDE we usually allow solutions to be distributions (aka generalised functions). I'll spare you the details; you'll have to read a book on PDE by a mathematician to understand that there is a deep connection between PDE and distributions. Long story short, the *distributional* solution of
$$
(k^2-\omega^2)u(k,\omega)=0
$$
is
$$
u(k,\omega)=f(k,\omega)\delta(k^2-\omega^2)
$$
for an arbitrary function $f$. This function satisfies $(k^2-\omega^2)u=0$ but $u\neq 0$. (Note that I set $c=1$ to simplify the notation).

You can find some more details about this approach in [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216183/a-question-on-using-fourier-decomposition-to-solve-the-klein-gordon-equation/216194#216194), where I solve $(\partial^2+m^2)\phi=0$. Note that in that post, $\partial^2=\nabla^2-\partial_t^2$; to get the standard wave equation, you can take $m=0$.

Comment: Thank you! The solution of $u(k,\omega)$ is thus an arbitrary function $f(k,\omega)$ on the line $k=\frac{\omega}{c}$ and zero elsewhere? Could you perhaps recommend me a mathematical PDE book to help me explain exactly the step between your 1st and 2nd equation?

Comment: @Carucel 1) yes, exactly. 2) I've asked a friend of mine who's a mathematician, and he told me that the best reference for PDE is [Evans' Partial Differential Equations](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821849743/?tag=stackoverfl08-20), but depending on your background it may be slightly too advanced and technical.  In [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827) math.SE post there are more recommendations on the topic.

Comment: Wow thank you very much! The book seems very interesting of appropiate level. Thank you a lot!