# How to derive this expression for the free scalar field in QFT? (Peskin & Schroeder)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, harmonic-oscillator, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

In the introductory text to quantum field theory by Peskin & Schroeder, they state that in analogy to the simple harmonic oscillator in quantum mechanics, the free scalar field can be expressed as:

$$\phi(\vec{x}) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}} \left( a_p e^{i \vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} + a^{\dagger}_p e^{-i \vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} \right) \tag{2.25}$$

In quantum mechanics $\phi$ would be written as:

$$\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}} \left( a + a^{\dagger} \right)$$

I can see the similarities between the two expressions, as well as the fact that one may expand the free Klein-Gordon field as:

$$\phi(\vec{x},t) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i \vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} \phi(\vec{p},t).\tag{2.20b} $$

However I don't get how to reach the final expression given above, especially the exponential with negative sign in the second term. It's probably just a small thing that I am not seeing, but I would be thankful if somebody could give me a hint.

Comment: related: [A question on using Fourier decomposition to solve the Klein Gordon equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216183/84967) and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll adopt the abbreviation $kx:=k_0x^0-\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}$.
The Klein-Gordon equation $(\square +m^2)\phi=0$ can be solved by a Fourier transform. Writing $\phi(x)=\int d^4ke^{-ikx}\tilde{\phi}(k)$ we get $(k^2-m^2)\tilde{\phi}(k)=0$, i.e. $\tilde{\phi}(k)=\tilde{\varphi}(k)\delta(k^2-m^2)$ for some function $\tilde{\varphi}(k)$. Using$$\delta(k^2-m^2)=\dfrac{\delta(k_0-\omega_\mathbf{k})+\delta(k_0+\omega_\mathbf{k})}{2\omega_\mathbf{k}}$$gives$$\phi(x)=\int\dfrac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_\mathbf{k}}(a_+(k)e^{-ikx}+a_-^\ast(k)e^{ikx})$$with$$a_+(k):=(2pi)^3\tilde{\varphi}(\omega_\mathbf{k},\,\mathbf{k}),\,a_-(k):=(2pi)^3\tilde{\varphi}^\ast(-\omega_\mathbf{k},\,\mathbf{k}).$$For real $\phi$, $a_-=a_+^\dagger$, so defining $a:=a_+$ we're done. (You have an erroneous $\sqrt{}$ sign in the Lorentz-invariant integration operator.) Note in particular your $e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$ coefficient of $a_k$ is $e^{i(k_0x^0-kx)}$, but I've absorbed the $e^{ik_0x^0}$ factor into my definition of $a_k$ to make the above result's Lorentz-invariance manifest.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is very clear! Are you sure regarding the erroneous $\sqrt{}$? In Peskin it seems to be there (eq. 2.25, page 21), with $\omega_p = \sqrt{p^2 + m^2}$. Or maybe I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: I have one more question regarding the result you give for $\tilde{phi}(k)$ in your first paragraph: is the integral really there or is it just equal some function times the delta function?

Comment: @Julien (i) I'm referring to your first equation having $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_\mathbf{k}}}$. The frequency is of course already a square root. My answer's power counting is based on pp.47/8 [here](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnChalker/theory/lecture-notes.pdf). (ii) Ah, that was a mistake I've now fixed. There's a funny story there: while I originally wrote the answer I accidentally missed an integral sign or two, but I obviously overdid putting it into places.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's strange, in Peskin and in David Tong's notes there is a square root indeed, although I can see that there isn't in your link and I hear your argument. I don't have a link to Peskin, but the lectures of D. Tong (which you can find here: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf ) are based on Peskin I believe (see eq. 2.18 page 23).

Comment: Well, we definitely don't need the extra square root. As has been explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83260/lorentz-invariant-integration-measure), it's just the $1/k_0$ factor from the Dirac delta in my answer above.

Comment: The square root (or lack thereof) correspond to different conventions (some authors redefine $a\to \sqrt{2\omega} a$). Both conventions are perfectly fine.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks for clarifying that point. This is all clear now.

Comment: Actually I still have a problem which I didn't notice before: when I insert the sum of Dirac delta functions inside the Fourier transform integral, I get: $$\phi(x) \propto \int d^3 k \frac{1}{2\omega_k} \left(e^{i kx} \delta(k_0 - \omega_k) + e^{i kx} \delta(k_0 + \omega_k) \right) \varphi(k) = \int d^3 k \frac{1}{2\omega_k} \left(e^{i (\omega_k t - \vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})} \varphi(\omega_k, \vec{k}) + e^{i (-\omega_k t - \vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})} \varphi(-\omega_k, \vec{k}) \right)$$. My problem is related to the exponentials: the 1st term is fine, but how does the 2nd term turn to $e^{-i kx}$?

Comment: Ah never mind, this step is explained by @AccidentalFourierTransform in the link that he posted in the comment of the question.