# Different expression of $\Delta(x, m^2)=(2\pi)^{-3}\int e^{ip \cdot x}\theta(p^0)\delta(p^2+m^2)d^4p$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, kinematics, dirac-delta-distributions

Let $$\Delta(x, m^2)=(2\pi)^{-3}\int e^{ip \cdot x}\theta(p^0)\delta(p^2+m^2)d^4p.$$

Here $\theta$ is the step function at $0$.

I would like to show that this is the same as 
$$\Delta(x, m^2)=(2\pi)^{-3}\int \frac{e^{ip \cdot x}}{2\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}}d^3p.$$

However I cannot see how to proceed. Could anyone help me? These two appear in the Weinberg book and treated as the same, but I cannot prove it myself.

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the integral over $p_0$?

Comment: I tried but the delta function has its argument as $p^2$, where I am stuck.

Comment: Remember that $p^2 = -p_0^2 + p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^2$ (in the -+++ signature), and the [composition property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) of the delta function.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83260/2451 and links therein.

Comment: see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/216194/84967

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that there is a misprint, argument of delta-function should be $p^2-m^2$.

Consider case $p^0>0$, so the integral becomes
$$\int d^4p\delta(p^2-m^2)e^{ipx}=\int dp_0\int d^3p\delta(p_0^2-p^2-m^2)e^{ip_0t}e^{ipx},$$
where zeros of delta-function are
$$p_0=\pm\sqrt{p^2+m^2},$$
and delta function becomes
$$\delta(p_0^2-(p^2+m^2))=\frac{\delta(p_0-\sqrt{p^2+m^2})}{2\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}-\frac{\delta(p_0+\sqrt{p^2+m^2})}{2\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}.$$
Performing integration over $p_0$, we obtain
$$\int \frac{d^3p}{2\omega_p}e^{ip\cdot x},\quad \omega_p=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}.$$

What about term with $p_0=-\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$? Agument of square root is stricktly positive, so we forget about it.

Comment: About the misprint: OP did not specify the signature $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, so you may both be right.

Comment: Sorry, I follow the convention $-1, 1, 1, 1$.